# Why do I see ": String" added onto let statements in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

When I type this in VSCode:

```
let mut guess = String::new();
```

I see it changed to:

```
let mut guess: String = String::new();
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The latter is explicitly specifying the type, but it's not strictly required. VSCode is probably just being pedantic.

Comment: See also [How can I remove type annotation help when using rust-analyzer?](/q/69909997/2189130)

Answer (score 7):

These are called [inlay hints](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#inlay-hints). rust-analyzer shows you the inferred type of the variable so you know it, for easier code reading. VSCode does not actually change the code, just how it displays it.

If you don't like it, you can turn it off by setting `rust-analyzer.inlayHints.typeHints.enable` to `false`. This disables only this kind of inlay hints; there are many others you can control via [the settings from the group `rust-analyzer.inlayHints`](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#configuration).

Comment: There's also an action to disable it - CTRL+SHIFT+P (by default) and type "toggle inlay hints." Much easier manually tweaking settings.

Comment: Although I don't recommend disabling them, they are incredibly helpful once you get used to them. Whenever I use an editor that doesn't have them (like https://play.rust-lang.org/) I keep making silly mistakes and programming is much slower than with hints.

Comment: @Finomnis One nice trick is to explicitly type variables as `()` and then the compiler tells you the real type in the error message.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Yah that's what I usually do, but it's a lot more tedious than mouseover or inline hints